# induction on <k to k+1

Tags: graph-theory, induction

I was attempting to prove a problem in graph theory by the help of induction on the number of vertices in the graph. Usually, the parameter in the hypothesis is $k$ and in the induction step $k+1$, however, in solving my problem the parameter in the hypothesis is $a$ and in the induction step is $b$, where $a<b$ and by the removal of certain number of vertices in a controlled way from the graph in the induction step I am able to obtain a graph in hypothesis. Is such use of mathematical induction correct?

I have already asked a few people about this and none have given me a satisfactory answer. My professor said that if you can go from any $a<k$ in the hypothesis to $k+1$ in the induction then it is correct, here we are assuming that all the instances up to $k$ are correct in the hypothesis rather than the traditional way in which we assumed only the $k$ instance as true, which makes me think it is a circular proof.

Comment: This is known as the principle of strong induction. Logically, it stands on just as firm ground as the induction you're used to, as long as you do it correctly. In fact, that is closer to the true principle of induction the way it is defined in set theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strong Induction

By proving

(1) the statement is true for $n=1$

(2) if the statement is true for all positive integers $n$ with $n\le k$, then the statement is also true for $n=k+1$

we can conclude that the statement is true for all positive integers $n$.

---

With (1), the statement is true for $n=1$.

So the statement is true for all integers $n$ with $n\le1$. By (2), its is true for $n=2$.

Now the statement is true for all integers $n$ with $n\le2$. By (2), its is true for $n=3$.

The statement is true for all integers $n$ with $n\le3$. By (2), its is true for $n=4$.

$\dots$

This process can be repeated indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

Induction in a more general sense.

Let $A$ be a set and let $R$ be a relation on it such that for every non-empty $B\subseteq A$ some $b\in B$ exists with $xRb\implies x\notin B$.

A relation with that property is a so-called wellfounded relation. If $\mathcal P(a)$ denotes that element $a\in A$ has property $\mathcal P$ and this property is inherited in the sense that $\mathcal P(a)$ is true whenever $\mathcal P(b)$ is true for every $b\in A$ with $bRa$, then it follows that $\mathcal P(a)$ is true for every $a\in A$.

---

In order to prove this it is handsome to start with the assumption that $\mathcal P(a)$ is not true for some $a\in A$.

Then the set $B=\{a\in A\mid\neg\mathcal P(a)\}$ is not empty so it contains some element $b$ with $xRb\implies x\notin B\implies\mathcal P(x)$.

Then the inheritance gives that $\mathcal P(b)$ is true, and a contradiction is found.

---

Examples:

- $A=\mathbb N$ equipped with relation $R$ prescribed by $nRm\iff m=n+1$
- $A=\mathbb N$ equipped with relation $R$ prescribed by $nRm\iff m<n$

The first example is the induction with base case $n=1$ and inductionstep $\mathcal P(n)\implies\mathcal P(n+1)$.

The second example is often labeled as strong induction.